# How to send email and pass in HTTP GET request call to bypass authentication and receive cookies?

Tags: http, cookies, get, k6

I'm trying to send a GET call to a login page and bypass its login so that the session can be authorized and send back a session cookie.  The login page only accepts GET requests which is why I'm restricted to that.

Here's my code:

```
const res = http.get('https://xxxx.xxxxx.net/xxxx/xxxxx/xxx/xxxx/action?email=xxxx%40xxxxxx.com&password=xxxxxx-985');
```

I've also tried it doing this way:

```
https://xxxxx%40xxxxxx.com:Xxxxxx-985@xxxx.xxxxx.net/xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/
```

However when I try to print out the response session cookie, I get an empty object:

```
const vuJar = http.cookieJar();
const cookies = vuJar.cookiesForURL(res.url);

console.log('Cookie:' + JSON.stringify(cookies));
```

I replaced the @ character with %40, I don't believe it's necessary for digits or dashes.  Perhaps I'm not sending the email/password correctly?